# What are the duals of the following statements?

Tags: projective-geometry, duality-theorems

1. Two distinct points are on one and only one line.
2. There are at least three distinct points that do not lie on the same line.
3. Points are collinear if they all lie on the same line.
4. (Desargue's Theorem) If two triangles are so situated that the three lines through the pairs of corresponding vertices are concurrent, then the three intersection points of the pairs of their corresponding sides are collinear.

Help! I'm stuck in a discrete math class and haven't taken the introductory abstract course.

Comment: For the first one I have "Only one line can pass through two points." For the second I have "Any plane is made up of at least 3 points. There is one and only one plane that contains three points that do not lie on the same line." and the third:  "All lines that intersect at one point are concurrent." The fourth one has me stumped though I don't think anything I have is correct.I haven't learned anything about dual statements, I'm unsure of whether this is supposed to be a mathematical proof or not.

Comment: What do you mean by “dual”? This is tagged Euclidean geometry and not projective geometry, so you’re not referring to the most obvious possibility.

Comment: Sorry, we are learning about Euclidean geometry in class and I thought it was related. My professor doesn't stay on one topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Two distinct lines intersect at one and only one point.
2. There are at least three distinct lines that do not intersect at the same point.
3. Lines are concurrent if they all intersect at the same point.
4. the dual is the converse, Desargues' thm (if and only if version) is self-dual

another qn which asks for the dual of statements: [Dualize this Projective Geometry Statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163960/dualize-this-projective-geometry-statement)